# Merging values of an Array

Tags: objective-c

I have an array that contains all the names that I get from JSON

```
NSArray *name = [newResponseObject valueForKey:@"name"];
```

I also have another array that contains all the last names that I get from JSON.

```
 NSArray *lastname = [newResponseObject valueForKey:@"lastname"];
```

What I want to do achieve is creating another array that contains [name, lastname] and I want to display the values for my picker view. for example "John Smith".

I have tried using `arrayWithArray` but that just added all the values into one array.

What is the correct method to achieve this ?

Comment: `NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; for (NSDictionary *aDictionary in newReponseObject) { [result addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", aDictionary[@"name"], aDictionary[@"lastname"]] ]; }`? But giving `newResponseObject` but be quite helpful to answer your question.

Comment: Having two independent arrays containing related content is a really bad idea. Can you change the JSON response format as well? You should have an array of objects containing both keys. Many people, each person having its own first and last name.

Comment: Otherwise go for R4Ns solution. Write a loop and if you are really certain that both arrays are the same length, access both arrays in there. Also `-valueForKey:` is part of `NSKeyValueCoding`, you should access arrays with `-objectAtIndex:` and dictionaries using `-objectForKey:` unless you have a reason for using NSCoding

Comment: @Larme That basically is what I'm looking for and thanks

Comment: @JulianF.Weinert Yeah I completely understand what you mean but unfortunately I cannot edit the json format

Comment: Oh damn it. The sad truth about bad APIs ;) Glad you have a solution

Comment: Then, in `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` what about doing `NSDictionary *element = [newResponseObject objectAtIndexPath:row]; return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", element["name"], element[@"lastname"]];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you're planning on doing with them afterwards should dictate how you decide to store them.  As @Woodstock mentioned you can store them in an array of concatenated strings "name lastname" similar to option 1 from below.

But from your description it sounds like you may want to store them as an array of arrays similar to option 2 from below.

```
// option 1 storing them in concatonated strings
NSArray *firstNames = @[@"John", @"Ralph", @"Bob"];
NSArray *lastNames = @[@"Smith", @"Jones", @"Miller"];
NSMutableArray <NSString *> *firstAndLastNames = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSInteger index = 0; index < firstNames.count; index++) {
    [firstAndLastNames addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [firstNames objectAtIndex:index], [lastNames objectAtIndex:index]]];
}
NSLog(@"First and last names = %@", firstAndLastNames);
// option 2 storing them in arrays
NSMutableArray <NSArray *> *firstAndLastNamesInArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSInteger index2 = 0; index2 < firstNames.count; index2++) {
    [firstAndLastNamesInArray addObject:@[[firstNames objectAtIndex:index2], [lastNames objectAtIndex:index2]]];
}
NSLog(@"First and last names in array = %@", firstAndLastNamesInArray);
```

Which would result in outputs of:

#### Option 1:

```
First and last names = (
    "John Smith",
    "Ralph Jones",
    "Bob Miller"
)
```

#### Option 2:

```
First and last names in array = (
        (
        John,
        Smith
    ),
        (
        Ralph,
        Jones
    ),
        (
        Bob,
        Miller
    )
)
```

The benefit of using the second option is if you want to just get the first name or last name you can just find it by index (rather than having to attempt to separate the first and last names by space -- some first or last names also have spaces in them so this could mess up your logic of trying to fetch just one of the names if you use option 1).

i.e. using option 2 you can find the last name of the 3rd person by doing this:

```
[[firstAndLastNamesInArray objectAtIndex:2] objectAtIndex:1]
```

Another option would be to create a Person object and have it have properties firstName and lastName and then store an array of Person objects instead.

One other thing you didn't mention as well (but I'm assuming is true), is are these arrays you're fetching from the server in the correct order -- i.e. does firstName[3] correlate with lastName[3]?  Also are you always guaranteed to have a firstName and lastName for each person?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to achieve this.

Probably the easiest is to concatenate at source.

```
NSArray *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [newResponseObject valueForKey:@"name"], [newResponseObject valueForKey:@"lastname"]];
```

Comment: It really depends on what is `newResponseObject`. If `newResponseObject` is `@[@{@"name":@"name1", @"lastname":@"lastname1"}, @{@"name":@"name2", @"lastname":@"lastname2"}]` that could give a strange result. Seems fine with `@{@"name":@"name1", @"lastname":@"lastname1"}` I know that this piece of information is missing from the author, but if someone else comes here...